# How can elements made invisible by display:none be made visible again with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have this HTML setup so that these elements will not display until a certain function gets run. The HTML by itself is fine...

```
<div id="aftlogin">
    <div id="priv1" style="display: none;">
        <p>Welcome there!</p>
    </div>
    <div id="priv2" style="display: none;">
    </div>
    <div id="priv3" style="display: none;">
    </div>
    <div id="priv4" style="display: none;">
    </div>
    <div id="priv5" style="display: none;">
    </div>
</div>
```

...It's the JavaScript the screws everything up: this JavaScript function is supposed to make those elements visible again. The elements that become visible depend on the value stored in the variable "role":
*(I used block since visible is for the visible style, not the display style)*

```
if (role == "priv1") {
    document.getElementById("priv1").style.display = "block";
}
if (role == "priv2") {
    document.getElementById("priv1").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("priv2").style.display = "block";
}
if (role == "priv3") {
    document.getElementById("priv1").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("priv2").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("priv3").style.display = "block";
}
if (role == "priv4") {
    document.getElementById("priv1").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("priv2").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("priv3").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("priv4").style.display = "block";
}
if (role == "priv5") {
    document.getElementById("priv1").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("priv2").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("priv3").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("priv4").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("priv5").style.display = "block";
}
```

One way or another, the code doesn't work. If I don't comment it out, the entire function stops working, so it's hard to pinpoint exactly what the problem is. All the syntax is correct, so I have done something else that upset the JavaScript gods?

Here is a jsFiddle demo: https://jsfiddle.net/9p9xx8sz/

Comment: what is the var `role` ?

Comment: @thesublimeobject It just defines the level of access a user has on the page. The values are all listed out in the script - i.e. a user with priv5 has more rights than a user with priv3

Comment: You're aware that the condition in a `if` statement should be enclosed in `()`, and that the comparison operator is `==` rather than `=` (which is an assignment), right?

Comment: DONT FORGET == instead of =

Comment: Do you have any errors showing up in the console?

Comment: No, this still doesn't work. I'm not running this in a console; I'm updating a live web page on my server

Comment: All modern browsers have a console in their respective developer tools.

Comment: Also, jsFiddle apparently showing it working as expected: https://jsfiddle.net/enu6LLga/

Comment: Show us a fiddle of it not working.

Comment: @jcaron Oh, that console... yeah, no errors. Your fiddle works, it doesn't work on my server, this fiddle doesn't work either: https://jsfiddle.net/58mxy07p/

Comment: Well, you've made two functions but didn't actually invoke them.

Comment: The functions get run, I just didn't put that part in the script. Once a user clicks a button I omitted from the HTML, it starts the first function which then calls the second function. Other stuff in the second function does get run (I also omitted that). Sorry here is the right fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9p9xx8sz/

Comment: Works: https://jsfiddle.net/9p9xx8sz/1/ You need to step back and work on providing a full demo that actually represents the issue.

Comment: you hide `defLogin` and try to show `aftLogin` which is inside `defLogin` so it will be hidden by hidden parent

Comment: I see your DOM in dev tools, its a child

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with just CSS. This is a typical example of how you can really reduce your code base by using the power of CSS.

The beautify for stuff like privilege rights is you just add the role class to the top of your page and use CSS selectors to show and hide stuff.

Here is a fiddle that demonstrates:

https://jsfiddle.net/9p9xx8sz/3/

```css
#priv1,#priv2,#priv3,#priv4,#priv5 {
  display:none;
}
.priv1 #priv1 {
  display:block;
}
.priv2 #priv1, .priv2 #priv2 {
  display:block;
}
.priv3 #priv1, .priv3 #priv2,.priv3 #priv3 {
  display:block;
} 
.priv4 #priv1,.priv4 #priv2,.priv4 #priv3,.priv4 #priv4 {
  display:block;
}
.priv5 #priv1,.priv5 #priv2,.priv5 #priv3,.priv5 #priv4,.priv5 #priv5 {
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<div id="aftlogin" class="priv1" >
   <div id="priv1" >
    <p>Welcome there!</p>
   </div>
   <div id="priv2" >
   </div>
   <div id="priv3" >
   </div>
   <div id="priv4" >
   </div>
   <div id="priv5" >
   </div>
</div>
```

In this updated fiddle below I have some JS that adds the role dynamically and turns on the correct divs using just CSS.

https://jsfiddle.net/9p9xx8sz/5/

Comment: Thanks, but I needed JS because it was only supposed to show the elements AFTER a user clicked a button and some logic was TRUE. Otherwise, it should not display. Otherwise yes, I would have used CSS

Comment: Yeah well that is the point. When the user clicks the login button then you apply the role as a class to the top. Then the correct elements all show. Dead fast, dead simple and extremely powerful. It's the way to go bud!

Comment: I'm not sure I follow... there's no logic in the example you provided... how it would know whether to hide the element or not?

Comment: Its simple. In your function you dont need all that code you just  do document.getElementById("aftlogin").className=role; and it will work.

Comment: And remove the initial class value <div id="aftlogin" class=""> I will update my example.

Comment: See update and fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/9p9xx8sz/5/

Comment: Tested this out... doesn't work. Take a look at http://interlinked.x10host.com/account/ - I'll leave this version up there for a few minutes before I restore the working version

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136113/discussion-between-martinwebb-and-interlinked).

Comment: Looked at users site. If the code is used correctly it works fine.

Comment: Thanks for this tip. I marked this as Answer because I like this so much. I got the code working. Also, the CSS in your answer has a bug in it, can you please fix that? Thanks! (you can see my webpage for what I did to fix it)

Comment: I have updated it fully.

Answer (score 1):

After reviewing your page I noticed that you have the `div` element you want to show inside the `parent` element being hidden at the same time.

Move your element so it is a sibling and it will solve the issue!